# C# Xamarin load image from url

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to load an image from a url string. Below code is an array of items, where `Photo` is what loads the image. Normally I included the image from my hard disk and loaded that image in by `Photo = "image_name.jpg"`

This is the first code:

```
public MainPageViewModel()
{        
    items.Add(new CardStackView.Item() { Name = "Title 1", Photo = " xxx ", Description = "Desc 1" });
    items.Add(new CardStackView.Item() { Name = "Title 2", Photo = " xxx ", Description = "Desc 2" });
    items.Add(new CardStackView.Item() { Name = "Title 3", Photo = " xxx ", Description = "Desc 3" });
    items.Add(new CardStackView.Item() { Name = "Title 4", Photo = " xxx ", Description = "Desc 4" });
    items.Add(new CardStackView.Item() { Name = "Title 5", Photo = " xxx ", Description = "Desc 5" });
    items.Add(new CardStackView.Item() { Name = "Title 6", Photo = " xxx ", Description = "Desc 6" });
}
```

I want `xxx` to be my url example `https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300`.

This piece of code is where I display the image:

```
Photo = new Image()
{
    InputTransparent = true,
    Aspect = Aspect.Fill,
    Scale = 0.95
};

view.Children.Add(Photo,
                  Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { double w = parent.Width * 1; return ((parent.Width - w) / 2); }),
                  Constraint.Constant(10),
                  Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Width; }),
                  Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return (parent.Height* 0.80); }));
```

Please note that these two pieces of code *is not* in the same file, but in two separate files.

I hope this isn't a duplicate, because I have not been able to find any solution to my problem.

Comment: Try https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Comment: What is the question or problem?

Comment: @EvZ "im trying to load an image from a url string."

Comment: @TheGejr So what is the problem with it? Does it crash the app? Does it simply not showing the image? Be more specific.

Comment: @EvZ no im trying to find a way to display the image, simply pasting a url doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @TheGejr https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/ check the "ImageSource" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Source` of your `Image` Element:

```
Photo = new Image()
{
    InputTransparent = true,
    Aspect = Aspect.Fill,
    Scale = 0.95,
    Source = "https://your_image_url.com/the_image.png"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `Binding`,Basically you need only to set value for the `Source`. try the following:

```
  <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" WidthRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" />
```